# Null reference exception unhandled in my program

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting an error "**Null reference exception was unhandled**" and "**Object reference not set to an instance of the object**" when I run my code.

**Stack trace**

```
>   Excel1.exe!Excel1.Program.GetAllTemplateNames(string strParam, string strRetVal) Line 121   C#
    Excel1.exe!Excel1.Program.ProcessInput(string strRetVal, string strFunctionName, string strParam1, string strParam2, string strParam3, string strParam4, Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TemplateData tData, Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TaskInstance tInstance, int tID) Line 77 + 0x23 bytes    C#
    Excel1.exe!Excel1.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 66 + 0x20 bytes  C#
```

Comment: can you please give the line (from the stacktrace or by using the debugger)? - Should be a trivial thing to debug - but to read and interpret all your code as a human without any clue to the exact spot? ...

Comment: Thanks but the Linie 121 correseponds to which pice of code? - Yeah I know I'm lazy, I just don't want to count the 121 lines myself while you can do a simple <Ctrl>-<G>

Comment: this line   List<Excel1.MWMClient.MWMServiceProxy.TemplateData> templateData = templateClient.GetAllTemplate(siteID).ToList();  you can find this line in the first method after the end of switch statement :)

Comment: Why are you creating new `tData` and `tInstance` instances in a for loop with the same values? Why not create one and re-use?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not initializing the `taskClient` and `templateClient` before using them.  I don't see any calls to your `TemplateImpl()` and `TaskImpl()` where you initialize those.

Comment: where and how do i initialize them both? Can you please guide me?

Comment: just like you have in the methods I mentioned, `templateClient = new Excel1.MW...` Just call those methods in the Main method, maybe right before the for loop.

Comment: can you please be more clear dear friend? I fail to understand u. A little code perhaps might help.

Comment: @user1463269 try `TemplateImpl(); TaskImpl();` right before the `for` loop in your `Main` method.